# Access column with in another column header

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I opened a .mat file in python. I can see that there is one main column named 'CloudData' within the CloudData there are two columns 'Points' and 'RGB'. I can access the Points columns by using:

```
points_data=(data['CloudData']['Points'][0:1])
```

where data is the name of the file read in python using scipy.io. But when i try to read the data values, which is inside RGB as below:

```
channel_data=(data['RGB']['data_values'])
```

I get the error complaining:
KeyError: 'RGB'

Is there any consideration to be taken after opening .mat file in python?
Actually in the Matlab, the variable data_values is displayed with CloudData.RGB.data_values as title on the variable viewer window.

For the first step, i want to read the values inside the RGB header, which is inside CloudData.

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer? Just because I told you to take a look into the `numpy` documentation for further information on how to handle `np.ndarray`s? I solved your problem with accessing `RGB`. That was what you asked for. You can open a new question about how to access the data stored in the array. But withdrawing the accepted answer should not be connected to asking another question...

Comment: So why did you unaccept my answer **again**? It is still the solution to your question and I can't change it if your problem changes. You really should ask a new question instead of withdrawing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

From what you wrote it looks to me that you should access `RGB` with

```
channel_data = (data['CloudData']['RGB'][0:1])
```

or

```
channel_data = (data['CloudData']['RGB']['data_values'][0:1])
```

depending on how you `.mat` file is constructed in matlab.

Comment: But it does work with `Points`? So there is an error in your description. Please update your description with a minimum working example or at least enough information to know the structure of your mat-file.

Comment: Sorry i missed the complete detail. The first method works but the second one shows error like this:
IndexError: only integers, slices (:), ellipsis (...), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: Yeah, this is because there most probably is no sub-`dict` in `RGB`, and thus you try to index the `ndarray` (or whatevery type is stored there) in `RGB` with the index `data_values`, which is not a valid index for a `np.ndarray`. But this is only guessing, since the information provided is quite sparse. If the first method works, I'd be thankful for being marked as correct answer.

Comment: thats the valid reason i think. But how to convert the RGB into a dict or how do i access data_values from RGB. Since i see that CloudData is the main key of the dictionary and Points and RGB are the values. But RGB has two more fields 'name' of type string (which i dont need i guess) and data_values of type '354*1 single' as displayed by the matlab.

Comment: What is the output of `type(data['CloudData']['RGB'])`? If it is `np.ndarray`, it is a numpy array and you can access the values by slicing. If it is a `dict`, try `data['CloudData']['RGB'].keys()` to see which keys are in the `dict` and then `data['CloudData']['RGB'].items()` to see under which key your data is stored. By the way. By having 15 reputation you just earned the privilege to upvote.

Comment: how do i get the data_values from numpy.ndarray? when i access all rows and all columns i get like:

 ...,
       [43.],
       [42.],
       [43.]], dtype=float32))]], dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('data_values', 'O')])
  array([[(array(['intensities'], dtype='<U11'), array([[43.],
       [44.],
       [44.],
       ...,

I dont want intensities, only data_values

Comment: Could you please add some correct code formatting and type information (in the way I posted above) so that I don't have to be able to do telepathic mind reading to get the information that I need?

Comment: Nonono, that is something completely different again. I just need the `type`s of the `RGB` value in the `CloudData`-`dict` (or whatevery this structure's `type` is). Please just use `type(data['CloudData']['RGB'])` and show me the output.

Comment: The type of this:`(data['CloudData']['RGB'])`  is numpy.ndarray. In matlab, the view of CloudData.RGB shows two Columns i.e. Field (name and data_values) and  Values has 'Intensities' and 354 X 1 meaning that data_values is of type 354 X 1 Single.  If i run: `channel=(data['CloudData']['RGB'][:]` I get the output something like: : 
`..., [43.], [42.], [43.]], dtype=float32))]], dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('data_values', 'O')]) array([[(array(['intensities'], dtype='<U11'), array([[43.], [44.], [44.], ...,`

Comment: `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[array([[(array(['intensities'], dtype='<U11'), array([[33.],
       [33.],
       [34.],
       [33.],
........
[33.]], dtype=float32))]], dtype=[('name', 'O'), ('values', 'O')])
  array([[(array(['intensities'], dtype='<U11'), array([[33.],
       [33.],..........`

i have skipped some of the middle values

Comment: Yeah, so if you do `channel = data['CloudData']['RGB']`, `channel` is an `np.ndarray` containing the data of `RGB`. You can now access `channel` like you would access any `np.ndarray`. If you have trouble with that, you should take a look into the `numpy` documentation and some `numpy` tutorials.